# Finding the minimum representation of a positive integer as the sum of three nonzero squares

Tags: reference-request, sums-of-squares

[n.b. This is a crosspost/nuancing of [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730556/are-there-ways-to-generate-alternative-representations-of-a-number-as-the-sum-of).]

Assume we have a positive integer $n$ which is already known to be the sum of the squares of three nonzero integers — for example,

$$
n = 451 = 19^2 + 9^2 + 3^2.
$$

As it turns out, this particular $n$ has are several other such representations, because

$$
  n = 451 = 15^2 + 15^2 + 1^2
= 21^2 + 3^2 + 1^2
= 17^2 + 9^2 + 9^2
= 19^2 + 9^2 + 3^2.
$$

I know there are ways of determining whether a given number has such a representation, [calculating how many representations a given number has](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730556/are-there-ways-to-generate-alternative-representations-of-a-number-as-the-sum-of), and so on. What I am hoping to find — or develop myself, if necessary — is a way of determining the “minimum” representation

$$n = a^2+b^2+c^2, \qquad abc \ne 0$$

where “minimum” is either defined as the minimum “root sum” $a+b+c$ (or $|a|+|b|+|c|$ or $|a+b+c|$ or sim.) or sum with the smallest term (e.g., $a \ge b \ge c \ge 1$ and $c$ is minimal amongst all possible representations).

Has this already been done? Is there any literature working in this direction?